# Where to find current user info inside the user JSON object?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, mean-stack

I am trying to find out how to get certain data belonging to the current logged-in user such as full name, email, etc.

The Firefox console outputs this:

```
----- header.component.ts -----
this.user:
{}
authService.getUser()
Object { _isScalar: false, source: {…} }
this.authService.me()
Object { _isScalar: false, _subscribe: me() }
-------------------------------
```

This prints out what the authService can provide using console.log() (see the TypeScript code below).

**I look through the Object returned by the authService.getUser() method and also the one returned by the this.authService.me() method, but I cannot manage to find where any of the info is located.**

I noticed in the HTML code (in a part that was made by the Mean.io generator and not by me) that it references "user.fullname" to display the user's full name in the header bar, but how? And how would you access other pieces of information such as the user's email, phone number, etc?

My profile component TypeScript file looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthService } from '../auth/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() user: any = {};

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("----- header.component.ts -----");
    console.log("this.user:");
    console.log(this.user);
    console.log("-------------------------------");
  }

  profile(): void {
    this.navigate('/profile');
  }

  logout(): void {
    this.authService.signOut();
    this.navigate('/auth/login');
  }

  navigate(link): void {
    this.router.navigate([link]);
  }

}
```

And my profile component HTML file looks like this:

```
<header >
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=ZCOOL+XiaoWei" rel="stylesheet">

  <mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <a [routerLink]="['/']" class="logo"></a>
    <a [routerLink]="['/']" class="toolbar-buttons"> Home </a>
    <a class="toolbar-buttons"> Deals </a>
    <a [routerLink]="['/about']" class="toolbar-buttons"> About </a>

    <span class="example-spacer"></span>
    <a class="links side" [routerLink]="['/auth/login']" *ngIf="!user">Login</a>
    <div>
      <a class="links side" *ngIf="user" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
        <mat-icon>account_circle</mat-icon>{{user.fullname}}
      </a>
      <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
        <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="user && user.isAdmin" [routerLink]="['/admin']">admin</button>
        <button mat-menu-item (click)="logout()">logout</button>
        <button mat-menu-item (click)="profile()">profile</button>
      </mat-menu>
    </div>
  </mat-toolbar>
</header>
```

Comment: Your `HeaderComponent` has an `@Input() user` property, which means it expects its parent component to pass the `user` reference to it. Please share where this `HeaderComponent` is used.

Comment: Please provide stackblitz if the posted answer does not help you

Comment: @ashish.gd what does @Input() mean? Does the '@' mean it is a decorator or something similar? I'm asking this because you said that it expects its parent component to pass the user reference to it. Also yes, I will find and share the parent component TS file asap.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale what do you mean stackblitz?

Comment: @JoshuaReeve See [here](https://stackblitz.com/), it is an online code editor for a web application or mostly uses for `Angular`

Comment: Yes, `@Input` is Angular's way of decorating the `user` property as an input property. It enables us to use the property as html attribute when using the headerComponent in other templates. Example: `<app-header [user]="userRef"></app-header>`. The `userRef` here is the user reference variable in the parent component TS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the user is not settled instantly, It waits for some ajax response, You could use ngOnChanges event and then access the user object like this

```
ngOnChanges(){
   if(this.user && this.user.fullname){
      //Do your work here
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok, this works for the header component (for testing purposes) but it is not working on a different component because the ngOnChanges() is not being called.